# Delphi XE keyboard errors

Tags: delphi, ide, keyboard, delphi-xe

We have a machine running Delphi XE Professional that will change the value of some keys when typing in the IDE. It will change letters and number keys into a digit. The next key pressed will enter the next number in sequence up to 9 and then it will start over at 0.

I haven't found anything similar posted anywhere else, but its not exactly an easy thing to search on.

Here are some facts:

- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit SP 1
- Delphi XE with and without Update 1 (Installing Update 1 was the first thing we tried to fix it)
- Acer Prestige Laptop

1. The digits cycle to nine and start over at zero.
2. Typing into anything except the Delphi IDE editor results in the correct key value.
3. Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and a key gives the corresponding symbol for the shifted number. For example, if the next number would be `5`, pressing `Shift` and a key gives you `%`.
4. Holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and a key does the appropriate function.  <kbd>ALT-F</kbd> will open the File menu.
5. Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and a key does the appropriate function.  <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> does Undo.
6. Most punctuation, such as  `,.<>/?`, works normally.
7. Quitting Delphi sometimes corrects it for a while, but not always.
8. Restarting Windows does the same.
9. The problem starts without apparent reason. Sometimes immediately, other times after a few minutes or hours.
10. This happens with either the integrated keyboard or the external USB keyboard.
11. Starting Delphi without the keyboard makes no difference.
12. No software is installed for the external keyboard for accelerator keys.
13. We have not taken the painful step of reinstalling Delphi.
14. Turning off Code Insight made no difference.

Comment: Have you got more than one keyboard layout? (If not, can you add one, possibly in a different language? Then, after adding,) Does the problem manifest itself likewise in all the layouts available? And with what particular layout are you presently experiencing the issue?

Comment: @Andriy - This is a U.S. English configuration. I'll ask him if he can try added another layout.<br>
@iamjoosy - It happens with all of the alpha and numeric keys, and it changes value after every keypress.

Comment: Because you mentioned Delphi I immediately assumed that this issue only pertains to working in Delphi environment. But then I started having doubts whether it was correct of me to assume so. Could you please confirm or deny this? I.e. does the problem only occurs when you are typing in Delphi, and not in any other program?

Comment: I mean, does it occur in all programs likewise *after* (and *because*) you start Delphi, or in Delphi only?

Comment: @Andriy - It only occurs inside the Delphi editor. Delphi dialog boxes show text normally. All other applications work normally at all times. The only way to get rid of the problem is to exit Delphi and restart. The problem will reocurr at some point again, sometimes immediatly other times not for days or hours.

Comment: Good luck with this. This is one of those problems that occurs on your system and your system alone.

Comment: I tend to agree with @David, I'm afraid. Anyway, I would possibly try the method that helped [this guy](http://www.chiefdelphi.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-49936.html): reinstalling the keyboard driver in Windows Safe Mode. Admittedly, there's much difference between his situation and yours: different model of Acer, different version of Windows, no Delphi, apparently different manifestation of the problem. Possibly, the only common thing, apart from the fact that it was Acer, was that the keyboard's erratic behavior was sporadically recurring. Still, as I said, I would give it a try.

Comment: @Andriy - Thanks for the link. It's probably worth a try since it doesn't take a lot of effort to reinstall the driver. SInce it happens with both the external and internal keyboard I think it's going to come down to reinstalling Delphi.  He went on vacation, I don't know if we will do it before next week.  I'll post an update when I get word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the *Comcast* provided *Constant Guard Protection Suite*, specifically the *Guarded ID* component. It was only intermittent for us, but others saw constant problems in game software such as WoW.

Closing the *Guarded ID* component in the notification area makes the issue go away.

*Comcast* recommends unistalling the component in Add/Remove Programs or it's equivalent, but some users have found that updating the suite may bring it back.

Link to *Comcast*'s support page for the issue:
http://customer.comcast.com/Pages/FAQViewer.aspx?Guid=9f60256f-7616-4445-b324-511011ff2c8a

Answer (score 1):

First step: Remove all 3rd party add-ins from Delphi. Uninstall them one at a time, so you know which one did it. 
Second step: Remove 3rd party packages.

Comment: Nothing but stock Delphi installed in this IDE.